# How do you check if a mercurial repo is in a clean state?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

As a user, I usually use `hg st` to check the status of a repo, and verify that it is in a clean state, with no modified files.

Here I would like to do this programmatically. I know I can also use `hg st` for that, but the output is less than ideal for consumption by a computer program. Is there a better way to check whether a mercurial repo is in a clean state?

Comment: I don't see why the output is less than ideal for consumption by a computer program.  If there working copy is not clean, it outputs a status character, a space and the path to the file for each file that is not clean.  If it is clean, it doesn't output anything.  It doesn't get much easier than that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you issue the `hg identify --id` command, it will suffix the ID with a `+` character when the repository has modified files. (Note: this flag does not report untracked files.)

If you grep the output of this command for the `+` character, you can use the exit status to determine whether there are modifications or no:

```
$ hg init
$ hg identify --id | grep --quiet + ; echo $?
1
$ touch a
$ hg identify --id | grep --quiet + ; echo $?
1
$ hg add a
$ hg identify --id | grep --quiet + ; echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `hg summary`:

```
$ hg init
$ echo blablabla > test.txt
$ hg summary
parent: -1:000000000000 tip (empty repository)
branch: default
commit: 1 unknown (clean)
update: (current)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most major programming languages have HG APIs you can access.

Comment: What about `sh` or `CMD`?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be useful for other people searching this topic:

I agree to @SteveKayes [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010909/how-do-you-check-if-a-mercurial-repo-is-in-a-clean-state#comment14391545_11010909) that `hg status` is a good command for programmatic consumption.

Here is an example how to use it in a bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

cd /path/to/hg-repo

repo_status=`hg status | wc -l`
if [ $repo_status -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Repo is not clean"
else
    echo "Repo is clean"
fi
```